# Unipotent subgroup of $GL_n(K)$ has a common eigenvector

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

An element of $GL_n(K)$ is called unipotent if its charateristic polynomial is $(x-1)^n$. A subgroup $H$ of $GL_n(K)$ is called unipotent if every element of  $H$ is unipotent.

My question is: How to show the elements of $H$ has  a common eigenvector ?

In Alperin's Book: Groups and Representations, there's a proof (Propositon 13.28). But that requires the fact (Theorem 13.27) that an algbra generated by nilpotent elements is nilpotent.

Is there any elementary proof? Thanks.

Comment: It's much easier to work with nilpotent algebras than unipotent subgroups.  I think the smart approach here would be to try to come up with an elementary proof of theorem 13.27, i.e. that an algebra generated by nilpotent elements is nilpotent.

Comment: In particular, it would suffice to show that the elements a subalgebra of $\mathcal M_n(K)$ generated by nilpotent matrices have a common eigenvector.

Comment: The real workhorse here is theorem 26: if $A$ is an algebra (possibly without unit) and $A$ has no non-zero nilpotent ideals, then $A$ must be an algebra with unit.  A direct proof of this in the matrix case would result in a direct and certainly a more elementary proof of your result.  Note that given such an ideal, it is easy to produce a common eigenvector.

Comment: It's important to note that in 13.27, the assumption is that the algebra can be generated **as a $K$ vector space**.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, but here is an outline of the proof for 13.27 as presented in the book.

Suppose that $A$ is a (finite-dimensional?) $K$-algebra generated by nilpotent elements.

1. Without loss of generality (via extension of scalars), we suppose that $K$ is algebraically closed
2. Proceed by induction on $\dim_K(A)$. For dimension $1$ this holds trivially.
3. If $A$ has a non-zero nilpotent ideal $I$, then we note that $A/I$ is nilpotent by the inductive hypothesis and we're done.
4. By contradiction, we argue that such an ideal must exist. If $A$ has no non-zero nilpotent ideals, then $A$ is an algebra with unit (since this holds for any algebra with no non-zero nilpotent ideals). Moreover, since $A$ is an algebra with unit and no non-zero nilpotent ideals, we can conclude that $A$ is semisimple.  Since $A$ is semisimple, it is isomorphic to a direct sum of matrix algebras (with unit).
5. Let $B \subset \mathcal M_n(K)$ denote one of these matrix algebras. Because $A$ is generated as a vector space by nilpotent elements, so is $B$.  Let $M_1,\dots,M_k$ be a spanning set for $B$.  We see that $\operatorname{trace}(M_j) = 0$ for all $j$. This implies that $\operatorname{trace}(M) = 0$ for all $M \in B$.  However, $\operatorname{id} \in B$ satisfies $\operatorname{tr}(\operatorname{id}) = n$, so we have a contradiction.